# Uniqueness of the Galois element taking one place over $p$ to another

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In their article [Cebotarev and his density theorem](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Ehwl/papers/cheb.pdf), Stevenhagen and Lenstra give without proof some basic facts about places (see pages 13 and 14).

I am confused by the last one, which states:

> if $p$ does not divide $\Delta(f)$ [and $\psi$, $\psi'$ are two places over $p$], then the element $\tau \in G$ [such that $\psi' = \psi \circ \tau$] is uniquely determined by $\psi$ and $\psi'$.

To explain the notation, $f$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $G = \operatorname{Gal}(f)$.

I am confused since I normally think of places of a number field over $p$ as corresponding to either prime ideals over $p$. In that case, it seems that the statement should be equivalent to saying that for two prime ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $p$, there is a *unique* galois element taking one to the other. This is false, as the Sage computation below shows:

```
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^4 - 10*x^2 + 1)
sage: ps = K.primes_above(17)
sage: [s for s in K.galois_group() if s(ps[0]) == ps[1]]
[(1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3)]
```

Am I misinterpreting the statement?

Comment: The way you normally think of places over $p$ is *not* how Lenstra and Stevenhagen define them (p. 13). Moreover, on p. 14 they write "In the formulation we have chosen, these facts are hard to find in the textbooks. This provides an attractive exercise for the reader." So you need to figure out what  "places over $p$" means to them; it is not what you think it means.